# Per-file IO trace (read and write rate in bytes per second) using Windows API

Tags: windows, winapi, io, paging

Is it possible to track the total amount of bytes read and written to the file `pagefile.sys`? The idea is to graph the rate of paging activity over time and identify memory bottleneck situations.

I've looked at [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.8) but it seems to notify only of changed events, but not bytes read/written.

I think there must be an API that allows it, since [Resource Monitor can do it (see first image)](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/clinth/2013/10/16/tracking-page-file-reads-and-writes/).

EDIT

As state in the link above, "The performance counters \Memory\Page/sec, \Memory\Page Reads/sec, and \Memory\Page Inputs/sec measure hard page faults (faults that must be resolved by disk) which *may* or *may not* be related to a page file or a low physical memory condition. Hard page faults are a normal function of the operating system and happen when reading the portions of image files (DLLs and EXEs) as they are needed, when reading memory mapped files, or when reading from a page file".

Therefore, performance counters are not enough for this task. I need to detect real page file activity and not "normal" hard faults.

Comment: What's kind of memory bottleneck situational you were investigating? A good tool to track the memory bottlenecks is performance counters. Is the link [Memory bottlenecks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/performance-tuning/role/hyper-v-server/detecting-virtualized-environment-bottlenecks#memory-bottlenecks) helpful?

Comment: @FeiXue we have 200+ windows virtual machines. Some of them show high values for pages input/output counters, even with lots of available memory. This probably happens because they are just reading/writing large files and not actually swapping, but these performance counters can't tell one situation from the other.

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is a way to query the information you are looking for. It is called performance counter in windows and there is a rich set of APIs for both consumer and producer of performance counters. Since you want to consume the performance counter, you should be looking at the consumer APIs. The following links will help you in getting the information that you need.

- [Performance Counters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/PerfCtrs/performance-counters-portal)
- [About Performance Coutners](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/PerfCtrs/about-performance-counters)
- [Consuming Counter Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/PerfCtrs/consuming-counter-data)

Comment: Sorry, there are no performance counters for pagefile read/write rate.